# Leaflet.VectorGrid throws error Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object

Tags: leaflet, react

This is a cross-post from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67032910/leaflet-vectorgrid-throws-error-input-data-is-not-a-valid-geojson-object). I am trying to use [Leaflet.VectorGrid.Slicer](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#vectorgrid-slicer), but I am getting error:

```
Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-river-16579?file=/src/VectorGrid.js)

**VectorGrid.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLeafletContext } from "@react-leaflet/core";
import L from "leaflet";
import geojsonvt from "geojson-vt";
import "leaflet.vectorgrid";
import { featureCollection, feature } from "@turf/helpers";

export default function VectorGrid({ assets }) {
  const { layerContainer, map } = useLeafletContext();

  const geoJsons = assets
    .filter((asset) => asset.mapPolygon)
    .map((asset) => feature(asset.mapPolygon.geometry));

  const slicerInput = featureCollection(geoJsons);

  console.log(slicerInput);

  const data = geojsonvt(slicerInput);

  const vectorGrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer(data, {
    rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
      sliced: {
        fillColor: "transparent",
        color: "blue",
        weight: 0.5,
      },
    },
    maxZoom: 22,
    indexMaxZoom: 5, // max zoom in the initial tile index
    interactive: true,
  });

  const container = layerContainer || map;

  useEffect(() => {
    container.addLayer(vectorGrid);
    return () => {
      container.removeLayer(vectorGrid);
    };
  }, [container, vectorGrid]);

  return null;
}
```

**temp_data.js**

```
export const dat = [
  {
    assetid: 1,
    id: 1,
    mapPolygon: {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [
          [
            [-104.98948, 39.64244],
            [-104.98953, 39.64244],
            [-104.98953, 39.64236],
            [-104.98918, 39.64236],
            [-104.98918, 39.64247],
            [-104.98948, 39.64247],
            [-104.98948, 39.64244],
          ],
        ],
      },
    },
    latitude: null,
    longitude: null,
  }, {
    assetid: 3,
    id: 3,
    mapPolygon: {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [
          [
            [-104.98793, 39.6444],
            [-104.98816, 39.64439],
            [-104.98816, 39.64438],
            [-104.98825, 39.64437],
            [-104.98825, 39.64432],
            [-104.98826, 39.64431],
            [-104.98826, 39.64429],
            [-104.98828, 39.64429],
            [-104.98827, 39.64422],
            [-104.988, 39.64422],
            [-104.98799, 39.64429],
            [-104.98793, 39.64429],
            [-104.98793, 39.6444],
          ],
        ],
      },
    },
    latitude: null,
    longitude: null,
  }]
```

Comment: I've closed the cross-post as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480206/invalid-geojson-object-angularjs-leafletjs - to quote the answer there, «That Leaflet's `L.GeoJSON` accepts just an array of features, doesn't make it a valid GeoJSON object, so you shouldn't call it a GeoJSON object. It's an array of GeoJSON feature objects. In a valid GeoJSON featurecollection object the feature array is contained like this: [...]»

Comment: Yes, https://geojsonlint.com/ was very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[geojsonlint](https://geojsonlint.com/) helped me to find out that FeatureCollection wasn't valid.